# Apache Spark: Cannot find symbol error Using array_contains

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, build-dependencies

I am new to apache spark and writing application that parses through a json file. One of the attributes in the json file is an array of strings. I want to run a query that selects a row if the array attribute does not contain the string "None". I found some solutions that use the array_contains method in the org.apache.spark.sql.functions package. However when I attempt to build my application I get the following cannot find symbol error:

[image: Cannot find symbol]

I am using Apache Spark 2.0, and maven to build my project. The code that I am attempting to compile:

```
import java.util.List;

import scala.Tuple2;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions;

import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;
public class temp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("testSpark")
                .enableHiveSupport()    
                .getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> df = spark.read().json("hdfs://XXXXXX.XXX:XXX/project/term/project.json");
        df.printSchema();
        Dataset<Row> filteredDF = df.select(col("user_id"),col("elite"));
        df.createOrReplaceTempView("usersTable");
        String val[] = {"None"};
        Dataset<Row> newDF = df.select(col("user_id"),col("elite").where(array_contains(col("elite"),"None")));
        newDF.show(10);
        JavaRDD<Row> users = filteredDF.toJavaRDD();
    }
}
```

Below is my pom.xml file:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>term</groupId>
  <artifactId>Data</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>

  <!-- specify java version needed??? -->
  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <!-- overriding src/java directory... -->
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/</sourceDirectory>
  </build>

  <!-- telling it to create a jar -->
  <packaging>jar</packaging>


  <!-- DEPENDENCIES -->
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
      <version>2.11.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
Dataset<Row> newDF = df.select(col("user_id"),col("elite").where(
        array_contains(col("elite"),"None")));
```

to add the `functions` class as a qualifier, like

```
Dataset<Row> newDF = df.select(col("user_id"),col("elite").where(
        functions.array_contains(col("elite"),"None")));
```

**or**, use a [Static Import](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html)

```
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.array_contains;
```

Comment: Thank you, I completely forgot that I needed to add the functions class as a qualifier. I have been looking at too many scala examples.